# how can I run FE and BE in a single root?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, tomcat, build

What I want to achieve is; I'm working on a Project built from React and Spring Boot technologies. At this moment both are running into separate directory/platform. I want to run both into a single root with Apache Tomcat.

What am I facing with it:

- I'm able to load homepage from the FE, and APIs also working well.
- Other routers are not working

For example:

`http://localhost:8080` is working fine and the homepage is loaded correctly,

`http://localhost:8080/dashboard` is showing me **404 - Page not found**

Have checked many examples and written `.htaccess` as well `web.xml` and `httpd.conf` to redirect all the requests on the `index.html` file. Following is the code that I have written into each file.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>create-react-app-servlet</display-name>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/index.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

These solutions I found from the SOF as well some of the blogs but still, I'm not able to route on different routers. Let me know where I'm doing wrong and what is still missing in this configuration.

**Edit:**

I'm having a war file, and by copy-paste uploading, FE build into it.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve with these rewrite rules. Do you have a WAR file or an executable JAR?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli having a war file and copying FE build into it, also updated question. :)

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: It is when I'm merging both the ends into one, then I'm not able to redirect on react app's routes, it always shows me 404 - page not found.

Comment: You could go to https://www.jhipster.tech/ and create a React and Spring Boot App and checkout how they do

Comment: Try removing Thymeleaf dependency from the classpath and the dependency.
I also can be because of the spring-boot security jar on ur project classpath.
Try removing that too.

Comment: @Mossad thanks for the comment, but at this moment I'm not having any dependency of Thymeelaf.